# Save Timer HighScore

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, timer, save

I am currently working on a game were it has a timer go and the best time is the one that can complete the course the quickest. For example, the first run if I get 40 seconds that will be saved as the high score but if the second run I get 30 seconds that will be the new high score. My app currently does the opposite were if I get a higher time that will be the new high score.

Notes: Yes I have tried to switch the sign to less than '(t < PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("HighScore", 0))' but the issue then is that no time can beat "0" as a high score.

**Source Code C#:**

```
using System.Collections; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using UnityEngine; 
using UnityEngine.UI; 
using UnityEngine.Internal;

public class TImer : MonoBehaviour {

 public Text timerText;
 public Text highscore;
 private float startTime;
 private bool finished = false;



 void Start () {

     startTime = Time.time;
     highscore.text = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("HighScore", 0).ToString();
 }




 void Update ()
 {

     float t = Time.time - startTime;
     string minutes = ((int)t / 60).ToString ();
     string seconds = (t % 60).ToString ("f2");
     timerText.text = minutes + ":" + seconds;
     if (t > PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("HighScore", 0)) {
         PlayerPrefs.SetFloat ("HighScore", t);
         highscore.text = t.ToString ();
     } 
}
```

Comment: inside if statement insert "Debug.Log("Current time: " + t + " - Highest score: " + PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("HighScore", 0));" and paste output here

Comment: Current time: 8.58746 - Highest score: 8.58746
TImer:Update()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few problems.

1st if you want to save the lowest you need to do what Peter Bons suggested and compare using float.MaxValue

2nd you are updating the HighScore during the update, it should only be updated when the player finishes the game. What happens now is, you start the game, HighScore is set to 0 or something near 0 in the update. If you stores the lowest time as HighScore that will never work because the Player achieves the "highest" (or best) score at the start of the game.

With that in mind I made some changes in your code. Make sure you call GameFinished() when the player reaches the end of the level/game.

```
using System.Collections; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using UnityEngine; 
using UnityEngine.UI; 
using UnityEngine.Internal;

public class TImer : MonoBehaviour {

 public Text timerText;
 public Text highscore;
 private float startTime;
 private bool finished = false;

 void GameFinished()
 {
      float t = Time.time - startTime;
      if (t < PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("HighScore", float.MaxValue)) {
             PlayerPrefs.SetFloat ("HighScore", t);
             highscore.text = t.ToString ();
             PlayerPrefs.Save();
       } 
 }

 void Start () {

     startTime = Time.time;
     highscore.text = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("HighScore", 0).ToString();
 }


 void Update ()
 {

     float t = Time.time - startTime;
     string minutes = ((int)t / 60).ToString ();
     string seconds = (t % 60).ToString ("f2");
     timerText.text = minutes + ":" + seconds;

     if(/* Check if player finished the game */)
           GameFinished();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, if I am not mistaken the high score represent the shortest time. In that case you should check whether the playtime is less than the stored high score instead of a greater than comparison you do now.

Yes, you did write that you tried the opposite but then one can never beat a high score of 0 (which is the default for the first time the player plays the game). Solution is simple: set the default high score to a large number:

```
if (t < PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("HighScore", float.MaxValue)) { //Checks HighScore or compare with max value
     PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("HighScore", t);
     highscore.text = t.ToString();
     if (t < PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("HighScore", float.MaxValue)) {
         PlayerPrefs.SetFloat ("HighScore", t);
         highscore.text = t.ToString ();
         PlayerPrefs.Save();//Saves PlayerPrefs to save the HighScore that was changed
     } 
}
```

Now, the first time the game is played will always result in a new highscore. Subsequent games will be scored against that highscore.

Comment: I have tried what you said to do, but what happens is the Highscore number stays at 0 and doesn't move? Not changing depending on the time you get on the course. It seems that even though I set the default high score number to float.MaxValue it stays at 0.

Comment: If you debug using my change, does it enter `PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("HighScore", t);
` and if so, what are the values of `t` and of `PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("HighScore", 0)` right before the call to `highscore.text = t.ToString();
`?

Comment: Also, you do call `PlayerPrefs.Save()` after the highscore is modified to persist the changes. See https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.Save.html. Because if you don't next time `PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("HighScore", 0) ` will be 0 again.

Comment: It runs `PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("HighScore", 0)` at the start setting HS to 0. Although through debugging I found out that it never runs any of the functions inside the if statement. Does not run this code:  `PlayerPrefs.SetFloat ("HighScore", t);`
`highscore.text = t.ToString ();`

Comment: I am not an Unity exert but this might be the case of having already a value for HighScore. Can you somehow reset the preferences like this is the really first time you run the game? If not you can onetime(!) execute `PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("HighScore", float.MaxValue)` on start?

Comment: Yea I reinstalled the app, sadly same result. Do you by chance know of any source code that has a High Score Timer in C#.

Answer (score 0):

Change `if (t > PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("HighScore", 0))` to `if (t < PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("HighScore", 0) || PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("HighScore", 0) == 0)`

Comment: This results in the High Score timer being stuck at .02000000.